# Iterable<SearchCriteria> is not applicable for the arguments

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to create a specification class for Product class. It will has a Predicate class which will process searchCriterias.

I get an error when I try to itterate searchCriterias:

```
The method forEach(Consumer<? super SearchCriteria>) in the type Iterable<SearchCriteria> is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> key, <no type> criteria) -> {})
```

Here's my class:

```
public class ProductSpecifications implements Specification<Product>{

    // List of search criterias to be applied to 
    private final List<SearchCriteria> searchCriterias;

    public ProductSpecifications() {
        searchCriterias = new ArrayList<SearchCriteria>();
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Product> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {

        searchCriterias.forEach((key, criteria) -> {
        if (criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(">")) {
            return builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(
            root.<String> get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue().toString());
        } 
        ....
```

Here's my Search Criteria class:

```
public class SearchCriteria {
    private String key;
    private String operation;
    private Object value;
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to iterate `List` as `Map`. You have to change

```
searchCriterias.forEach((key, criteria) -> {
```

to

```
searchCriterias.forEach((criteria) -> {
```

Comment: Your answer is correct, but there are more problems in my code. It was a bad idea to implement specifications that way. So I decided to apply a single specification and merge them with when in service level.